# Kubernetes redis node not connecting with other

Tags: kubernetes, redis

I have 2 services 1 is my app and other one is redis. I have created 2 services and both are up and running. I have check logs redis pod is creating fine and app is also working but issue is in connecting app with redis its continuesly showing error of timeout.

analytics-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: analytics-container
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: analytics-container
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: analytics-container
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: analytics-container
          image: umaiz/analytics-worker:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8100
```

analytics-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: analytics-container
spec:
  selector:
    app: analytics-container
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8100
  type: NodePort
```

redis-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis-container
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis-container
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis-container
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: redis-container
          image: redis:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 6379
```

redis-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-container
spec:
  selector:
    app: redis-container
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 6379
  type: NodePort
```

kubectl get pods

```
NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
analytics-container-d947cc46d-dkxjd   1/1     Running   0          2m58s
redis-container-d4df859c-qg4q9        1/1     Running   0          2m58s
```

kubectl get services

```
NAME                  TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
analytics-container   NodePort    10.100.159.64    <none>        8100:31464/TCP   3m3s
kubernetes            ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          5m9s
redis-container       NodePort    10.103.206.102   <none>        6379:31772/TCP   3m3s
```

I try connect with clusterip 10.103.206.102 and port 31772 but its not connecting tried with 6379 as well.

Tried with pod name like this its showing its running. But don't know why its not connecting with other pods.

```
kubectl exec -it redis-container-d4df859c-qg4q9 -- redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> ping
PONG
```

Also One more thing I try to upload it on GKE when I upload redis service and connect ip and port in my local project its connecting on it but same when i try on to connect that redis ip on k8s app node its not connecting -_-

Comment: You should be able to use the Service's name as a DNS name, with its configured port; `redis-container:6379`.  What error do you get?

Comment: @DavidMaze I have try host as redis-container and port as 6379 but its showing error [ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND redis-container

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the above setup in managed kuberntes[[E2E Networks Cloud]](https://www.e2enetworks.com/), the first time when I ran the application I had got the TIMEDOUT error.

```
NAME                     TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)          AGE
analytics-container   LoadBalancer   10.96.241.249    116.204.172.41   8100:30625/TCP   4h49m
nginx-pod             ClusterIP      10.109.194.103   <none>           80/TCP           67m
redis-container       NodePort       10.105.102.196   <none>           6379:32054/TCP   4h2m
```

As observed in the screenshot you shared, the service name is not matching with that of mentioned in the config.js file. So made the change in the config file from **redis-service** -> **redis-container**, after which the TIMEDOUT error was solved.

```
REDIS: {
host: "redis-container", -> Added the correct service name
port: 6379,
password: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD || null,
},
```

After making the change, it showed the pod was connected to redis.(PFA)
[connection](https://www.e2enetworks.com/)

To verify the connection, I was able telnet the port 6379 from the analytics pod.

```
﻿root@analytics-564c757cfd-157p4:/usr/src/app# telnet 10.105.102.196 80
Trying 10.105.102.196...
^C
root@analytics-564c757cfd-157p4:/usr/src/app# telnet 10.10.102.196 6379
Trying 10.105.102.196...
Connected to 10.105.102.196.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Additionally verified by pinging the endpoint IP(i.e. the Pod IP) of the redis-container.

```
﻿NAME          ENDPOINTS           AGE
analytics     10.244.2.4:8100     5h3m
nginx-pod     10.244.2.6:80       81m
redis         10.244.2.5:6379     4h16m
```

When trying to access the content of analytics container, I get the below output when I use the **LB IP:8100**

```
{"status":0,"errorMsg":"Token not present"}
```

> **NOTE** :I did observe that you had hard-coded the AWS credentials in the
> config file.

Answer (score 0):

In the service definition YAML, you are missing the target port that should point to container port from the pod. Use the below files and it should work.

Redis

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-container
spec:
  selector:
    app: redis-container
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 6379
      targetPort: 6379
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis-container
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis-container
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis-container
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: redis-container
          image: redis:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 6379
```

Analytics

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: analytics-container
spec:
  selector:
    app: analytics-container
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8100
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: analytics-container
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: analytics-container
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: analytics-container
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: analytics-container
          image: umaiz/analytics-worker:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8100
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Consider you are using a single YAML file for both `Service and Deployment` configurations.

###### This is particularly important because certain versions of Docker and Kubernetes have issues or you did something wrong in your YAML config file and that's why might be missing the target port.

By consolidating your Service and Deployment configurations into a single YAML file, you can enhance the setup and might fix all of these issues

```
1. Network Connectivity
2. Service Discovery
3. Port Configuration
4. Security Groups/Firewall
5. Redis Configuration
6. DNS Resolution
```

###### I'm hoping there might be no issue related to the list in your `YAML` configuration, but you can have a look at the `YAML` configuration and it will fix all.

##### Config

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment

Rest of the setup as you want

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service

Rest of the setup as you want
```

##### For example

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis-dep
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: redis
          image: redis:latest
          ports:
          - containerPort: 6379
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: redis
  ports:
    - name: redis
      protocol: TCP
      port: 6379
      targetPort: 6379
```

###### If I'm not wrong the `Redis` access URL will be: `redis-srv.default.svc.cluster.local:6379` and the analytics container app `YAML` configuration will be like this to access `Redis` services.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: analytics-container
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: analytics-container
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: analytics-container
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: analytics-container
          image: umaiz/analytics-worker:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8100
        # Add the following section to connect to Redis
        - name: redis-client
          image: redis:latest
          env:
            - name: REDIS_HOST
              value: redis-srv.default.svc.cluster.local
            - name: REDIS_PORT
              value: "6379"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: analytics-container
spec:
  selector:
    app: analytics-container
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8100
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: redis
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 6379
```